# which approach is best to get data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables and suppose having bulk of data

```
Table1                   Table2
Id  Name Address         Id  Table1Id Parents_Name Address
1   ABC  123ABC           1     1      DDD          Xyz
.   ...  ......           .     .      ...          ...
.   ...  ......           .     .      ...          ...
```

Now if i want solution in below format

```
Id  Name  Parents_Name
1   ABC      DDD
.   ...      ...
.   ...      ...
```

then which one will be best
**Subquery** or **join**

Comment: Normally use a simple join for that.

Comment: I am asking which one is best performance wise

Comment: try verifying execution plans of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Joins** and **subqueries** are both be used to query data from different tables and may even share the same query plan, but there are many differences between them.  Knowing the differences and when to use either a **join** or **subquery** to search data from one or more tables is key to mastering SQL.

**Joins** and **subqueries** are both used to combine data from different tables into a single result.  They share many similarities and differences.

**Subqueries** can be used to return either a scalar (single) value or a row set; whereas, **joins** are used to return rows.

A common use for a subquery may be to calculate a summary value for use in a query.  For instance we can use a subquery to help us obtain all products have a greater than average product price.

```
SELECT ProductID,
       Name,
       ListPrice,
       (SELECT AVG(ListPrice)
          FROM Production.Product) AS AvgListPrice
  FROM Production.Product
 WHERE ListPrice > (SELECT AVG(ListPrice)
  FROM Production.Product)
```

There are two subqueries in this SELECT statement.  The first’s purpose is to display the average list price of all products, the second’s purpose is for filtering out products less than or equal to the average list price.
Subquery Free Video Offer

Here the subquery is returning a single value which is then used filter out products.

Notice how the subqueries are queries unto themselves.  In this example you could paste the subquery, without the parenthesis, into a query window and run it.

Contrast this with a join whose main purpose of a join is to combine rows from one or more tables based on a match condition.  For example we can use a join display product names and models.

```
Select Product.Name,
       ProductModel.Name as ModelName
FROM   Production.product
       INNER JOIN Production.ProductModel
       ON Product.ProductModelID = ProductModel.ProductModelID
```

In this statement we’re using an INNER JOIN to match rows from both the Product and ProductModel tables.  Notice that the column ProducModel.Name is available for use throughout the query.

The combined row set is then available by the select statement for use to display, filter, or group by the columns.

This is different than the subquery.  There the subquery returns a result, which is immediately used.

**Note that join is an integral part of the select statement.  It can not stand on its own as a subquery can.**

A subquery is used to run a separate query from within the main query.  In many cases the returned value is displayed as a column or used in a filter condition such as where or having clause.  When a subquery incorporates a column from the main query it is said to be correlated.  In this way a sub query is somewhat like a join in that values from two or more tables can be compared.

Joins are used in the FROM clause of the WHERE statement; however, you’ll find subqueries used in most clauses such as the:

```
SELECT List – here a subqueries used to return single values are used.
WHERE clause– depending on the conditional operator you’ll see single value or row based subqueries.
FROM clause– It is typical to see row based result subqueries used here.
HAVING clause – In my experience scalar (single value) subqueries are used here.
```

Though joins and subqueries have many differences, they can be used to solve similar problems.  In fact just because you write a SQL statement as a subquery doesn’t mean the DBMS executes as such.

you can refer to this link for more details:-
http://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-and-subquery/

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you want an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.Id
    ,t1.Name
    ,t2.Parents_Name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.Table1Id = t1.Id
```

But you could also use an `OUTER JOIN` to always show rows from `table1` and show the matching rows from `table2`.

```
SELECT t1.Id
    ,t1.Name
    ,t2.Parents_Name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.Table1Id = t1.Id
```

Comment: It depends... on the size of your tables, your indexes, ... But you'd have to try it out and see the execution plans

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a join, which will almost certainly be much more efficient.  A quick google with give you much more information than you need to learn about the different types of joins available and how to use them, such as https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

Please create an index on the id of Table1 and Table1Id of Table2 and use this query.

```
Select t1.Id,
t1.Name,
t2.Parents_Name
from Table1 t1 
inner join 
Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.Table1Id
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, Join should be preferred considering query performance. Squbquery will require **IN** operator that is always a pain with bulk data. However it also depends in your indexing. Better you check both.